# How can I catch only a certain type of ValueError in Python?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, valueerror, raise

I process data and for some examples the data are problematic. Python raises a

> ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point.

Is there a possibility to catch Value errors only with the message `"Residuals are not finite in the initial point."`?
I tried:

```
try:
    [code that could raise the error]
except Exception as e:
    if e=='ValueError(\'Residuals are not finite in the initial point.\')':
        [do stuff I want when the Residuals are not finite]
    else:
        raise e
```

But it still raised the error all the time. Is there a way to achieve what I imagined?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try:
    [code that could raise the error]
except ValueError as e:
    if len(e.args) > 0 and e.args[0] == 'Residuals are not finite in the initial point.':
        [do stuff I want when the Residuals are not finite]
    else:
        raise e
```

You may have to check if `e.args[0]` exactly contains this string (provoke the error and print `e.args[0]`)

See also [documentation about `BaseException.args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args)

Comment: For completeness sake, you may want to reference the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), especially the paragraph that starts with "The except clause may". It might also be sane to check `if len(e.args)` first before trying to access `e.args[0]` in case the code raises more ValueErrors which have no inputs.

Comment: @Reti43 I have enhanced the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can catch a ValueError Exception like this:

```
try:

    #[code that could raise the error]

except ValueError as e:

    print("Residuals are not finite in the initial point. ...")
    #[do stuff I want when the Residuals are not finite]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because a `ValueError` can be thrown for many reasons. MaxS is interested specifically for a ValueError with the described message in the question.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to catch only those which show the message I mentioned.